# Confused about windows gadget

Tags: silverlight, windows-8, windows-desktop-gadgets

I have developed a Windows desktop gadget using Silverlight (MVVM pattern) and WCF.

I want to know whether it will work on Windows 8, since there is no option as sidebar in Windows 8.

If possible please tell what should I do to make it compatible with both Windows 7 and Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Desktop Gadgets are not supported on Win8: http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/microsoft-to-remove-desktop-gadgets-from-windows-8-1088122

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reuse some parts of your code to make a Windows 8 'immersive app' with a Live Tile. The C#/XAML stack in Windows 8 is quite similar to Silverlight (but not the same). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465136.aspx for a guide about the differences.